# How to make Sonatype's Nexus Repository to work with SpringSource’s EBR

Tags: maven-2, osgi, nexus, springsource

I'm looking to add the SpringSource EBR (Enterprise Bundle Repository: http://www.springsource.com/repository/) to Nexus as a proxy. My main reason to doing so is that SpringSource OSGi-fied various well known OSS projects (ex: Velocity, AspectJ...), making them easy to be included in OSGi runtimes.

Anyway, it seams that are some troubles with how Nexus "see" EBR since even that I can browse remotely the repository, it's not proxi-ed and correctly indexed at all.
As a hint what I observed is that Nexus doesn't see the direct maven groups (ex: org/...) as exposed by other Maven repositories (ex: Central, google...) but instead a separate **external** or **release** folder/root is inserted when navigating remotely.

Bellow are the SpringSource EBR repositories of my interest:

> ```
> <repository>  
>       <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>  
>       <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
>       <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url> 
>  </repository> 
>  <repository>  
>       <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>  
>       <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
>       <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url> 
>  </repository>
> ```

If this repositories are specified directly into a Maven project **pom.xml** everything is just fine, but not through Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add them as proxy repositories (and I suggest turning off indexing). At least it worked for me.

Comment: By turning off indexing you mean to disable loading the remote index ?

Comment: Are you able to browse the SpringSource repositories mentioned above in Nexus on "Browse Storage" and "Browse Index" tabs ?

Comment: @user68682 `By turning off indexing you mean to disable loading the remote index?` Yes. `Are you able to browse the SpringSource repositories mentioned above in Nexus` Can't confirm (by I confirm that I can get artifacts from it).

Comment: I have an exactly the same issue: added a proxy repo in sonartype nexus, set "Download Remote Indexes"=false, "Remote Storage Location"=http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release, added http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external repo similarly, then I added these 2 repo to Public Repositories Group - mvn build faild: "Failure to find org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.api:jar". Although w/o nexus repos - everything works fine. ???

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem, also. The key is to make sure that autorouting discovery is turned off for those repositories that do not provide prefixes or allow Nexus to scrape the URLs to generate a prefix file. To do this, visit the "Routing" tab in the repositories and untick the "Discovery" option.